# Extension of a function defined on a subspace of $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $S = [0,1]\cap\{\frac{q}{p^n}|q \in \mathbb{Z},n \in\mathbb{N}\}$. Assume that $S$ has the subspace topology induced from the inclusion $S \subseteq [0, 1]$. Will any bounded/ continuous/ uniformly continuous function on $S$ extend respectively to a bounded/continuous/uniformly continuous function on $[0,1]$?

The given space seems to be normal in $[0,1]$ (but I am unable to prove how). Hence, by Tietze extension theorem, I think any uniformly continuous function would extend to the same on $[0,1]$.But, I am unsure of continuity and boundedness. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: But the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ is not defined in $0=0/p\in S$.

Comment: @carciofo21 thanks for that. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any uniformly continuous function on a metric space can be extended to a uniformly continuous function on the closure. If the metric space is compact then we can further extend the function to a uniformly continuous function on the whole space by Tietze Theorem.

Any bounded function on  a subset of  a metric space extends to a bounded function on the whole space by just making it $0$ outside the subset.

Let $S$ be  a subset of  a metric space $(X,d)$. If every continuous function $f: S \to \mathbb R $ is bounded then it can be shown that $S$ is compact. Our set $S$ is not compact: $\frac {[rp^{n}]} {p^{n}} \to r$ for any $r \in [0,1]$, so $S$ is, in fact a dense proper subset. Hence there exist continuous functions on $S$ that cannot be extended to $[0,1]$.

Comment: so then is the answer yes to all extensions?

Comment: also, would the extensions be unique?

Comment: @vidyarthi It is not true that continuous functions can be extended to continuous functions. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Uniquenes of the extension is true only for the case of uniformly continuous functions.

Comment: how is that uniqueness is true only for uniformly continuous and not continuous?

Comment: Where is the question of uniqueness for continuous functins  when the extension need not even exist?